# JMeter joining string list

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a test run in jmeter that in a certain point extracts a list of strings from a json with the json extractor and should join this list with a comma separator to reuse as parameter in other request.

The problem is I can't find a way to join the strings all together since the JMeter only returns one item for each user (thread).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Beanshell post-processor after request where you are extracting data with extractor and put:

```
try {
    List<String> perUserSubmissionTickets = (List<String>) JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties()
                    .get("jsonExtractorResultList");
    perUserSubmissionTickets.add(vars.get("singleJsonExtraction"));
    JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties().put("jsonExtractorResultList");
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    List<String> perUserSubmissionTickets = new ArrayList<>();
    perUserSubmissionTickets.add(vars.get("singleJsonExtraction"));
    JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties().put("jsonExtractorResultList");
        }
```

With this you have created a List containing all extracted vaules. If you need to convert it to String of all values separed by comma do something like (when all values are extracted):

```
String commaSeparated;
for(String s : (List<String>) JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties()
                            .get("jsonExtractorResultList"))
    commaSeparated = commaSeparated + s + ",";
vars.put("commaSeparatedValues", commaSeparated.substring(0,str.length()-1));
```

After this you should have a string like: `data1,data2,dataN`

Remember to declare these import at begining of Beanshell Scripts:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: I have maybe misundestood your question a little bit, but you could make appropriate changes and add List of strings from one response to List stored as propery (as in my answer). Sorry, doing this from my head...